# Opening one screen from another

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to open one screen from another in an Android App. I copied the outline of the following code from a tutorial online and then tried to substitute my own screens. When I try to run the following code, I get a "Force Close" when I click the button on the first screen (the second screen never displays). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? There are four files: ScreenTestActivity.java, main.xml, screen2.java and screen2.xml.

```
ScreenTestActivity.java

package com.birdscreen.android.testscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ScreenTestActivity extends Activity
{
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
   {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
         Intent i = new Intent(ScreenTestActivity.this, screen2.class);
         startActivity(i);
         } 
      });
   }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="You are in the first Screen"
/>
<Button 
   android:id ="@+id/btnClick"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Open New Screen"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

screen2.java:

```
package com.birdscreen.android.testscreen;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class screen2 extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
        }
    }
```

screen2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="You are in the New Screen"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code, have you registered your second activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <activity android:name="screen2"></activity>

       <activity android:name="ScreenTestActivity"></activity>
```

put this 2 line of code in your androidmanifest.xml file